# Typescript nested arrow function callback is not working as expeceted

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, async-await, mysql2

this.Pool

```
import mysql2 from 'mysql2/promise';

this.Pool = mysql2.createPool({   
            host : "1",
            user : "2",
            password : "3",
            database : "4"
           })
```

```
    async createTable(table: string): Promise<void> {
        await this.Pool.getConnection(async (connection) => {
            await connection.query(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \`${table}\`(
                a INT,
                b INT

            );`);
            console.log("TABLE CREATED");
        });
    }
```

in this case, the code just waits to get promise

```
    async createTable(table: string): Promise<void> {
        await this.Pool.getConnection(async (connection) => {
            return await connection.query(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \`${table}\`(
                a INT,
                b INT

            );`);
            console.log("TABLE CREATED");
        });
    }
```

but it just works..

this seems a bit different what I know. I know that Javascript automatically returns a Promise even if an asynchronous function does not return anything. is there something wrong in code or my knowledge?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're running into? Is there a TS error from one of those snippets?

Comment: the console.log() statement is the issue since that returns undefined, so does the function.

Comment: @Derek The first nested function returns `undefined` because there's no explicit return; the second returns the `connection.query` result (the `console.log` isn't executed).

Comment: yes, hence why I said that was the issue.

Comment: @Derek Hm, I read that as "the console.log statement is the issue"--but it isn't; the return value of `console.log` is immaterial--it's not being returned in the first code, and not executed in the second.

Comment: oh, I'm sorry the console.log() is just for check statements so don't have to care about it.

and there's not a TS error but if I execute that code, it does not execute the query and just waits indefinitely. that's why I said **the code just waits to get promise**

Comment: "It just works." What were you expecting? If you're wondering, `async` functions ALWAYS return promises, so TypeScript isn't mad that you just implicitly do that.

Comment: usually, a function that takes a callback - e.g. `this.Pool.getConnection` in your code, won't return a Promise as well - does `const connection = await this.Pool.getConnection();` then run the query on the next line work?

Comment: Could you provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE?  Right now I imagine the behavior depends on things like `this.Pool` which aren't defined for us.  If you can make it easy for others to see what you're seeing, then they can more readily diagnose and debug.  Maybe you can provide a definition for it?  And give us whatever surrounding code is necessary to reproduce?  And if it depends on some third party library you might want to tag the question as such.

Comment: @Jaromanda X

oh, it's working well. so all the functions that take a callback does not return Promise implicitly?

Comment: not ususally if the callback is called asynchronously (nothing to do with async keyqord)

Comment: @jcalz I'm sorry. it's first time to ask question in stackoverflow and I just stayed up all night and was careless

Comment: So does the question depend on `mysql` and `node`?  I don't have either in my environment so I can't test it easily.  If it does depend maybe we can tag it?  If not can you refactor the example to remove it?  Or do you have a link to a web IDE project that shows the issue?  If I can test it I can (maybe) debug it.  If I have to pretend *I'm* a computer and try to run the code in my brain, there will be lots of errors but I'm a bad computer, so it wouldn't help.

Comment: @sdsadddf I'd wager most functions that take a callback *don't* return a promise, implicitly *or* explicitly. They're generally designed to use the callback for the code that runs after/during the method does its thing.

Answer (score 0):

Put your log statement between getting the value and returning it.

```
const ret =  await connection.query(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \`${table}\`(
                a INT,
                b INT

            );`);
console.log("TABLE CREATED");
return ret
```

Or inside the promise. (You do not need to even await in this case.)

```
return connection.query(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \`${table}\`(
                a INT,
                b INT

            );`).then(it=> {
              console.log("TABLE CREATED")
              return it 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said async function return promises if you don't return anything you should return the last operation of your code or variable .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).